# error TS2305: Module '"@spartacus/core"' has no exported member 'ActiveCartService' after upgrading spartacus 5.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

import { ActiveCartService } from '@spartacus/core';

The above import was works with Spartacus 3.4 and 4.3. but after upgrading to 5.0 am getting this error during yarn build.

error TS2305: Module '"@spartacus/core"' has no exported member 'ActiveCartService'

Answer (score 0):

Cart feature was moved to the `@spartacus/cart` library. And now can be lazy loaded.

For more, see the docs on updating Spartacus to v5: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/10a8bc7f635b4e3db6f6bb7880e58a7d/e047cd548b3f4c5ba08dbb5099f3c551.html?version=5